# Gstreamer RTSP client play time check

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

----command----
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.7.10:8554/ ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink

---

I send mp4 file via vlc to rtspserver and
Get the video with the gstreamer command above.

When I run the gstreamer command, the last line of the log shows the playback time of mp4 sent by vlc

I would like to know the same information in python-gstreamer.

Please teach me the way.

----log-----

Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
00:01:00 / 99:99:99

I know I can use python vlc but due to the situation, I want to use gstreamer and I want that information because I want to get the exact time

Comment: I think this is not the mp4 play time its just playtime on gstreamer side, because its an rtsp stream.